# How to boot a virtual machine as the primary desktop from text mode or DM under linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-kvm

I need to switch between linux distributions every couple weeks.  Virtual machines are great for this, but it'd be more convenient to run the virtual machine as my main desktop for a that period of time, rather than starting it from within a running window manager.

I would like to boot into text mode and just run a script that would start the VM-of-the-week in graphics mode.  Alternatively, it could be started from the login manager (e.g. lightdm) How can this be done with kvm or VirtualBox?  Thanks!

Comment: How did you try to approach this? Have you looked at the capability of remote xserver sessions?

Comment: Thanks for the input @Seth.  I've googled occasionally over the last month for "boot vm as desktop" and whatnot; explored using kvm with hardware passthrough, but I didn't figure out how use it on my single-graphics-card system; read about setting up thin clients, but there seem to be too many drawback.  I'll look into remote xserver sessions now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seth's comment about the remote xserver sessions led me in the right direction.  VirtualBox can be directly started on its own X session.  In the example below, we start an Ubuntu 15.04 image.

**From the command line**

Create a file named `startx_ubuntu1504` (or whatever you want to call it) in your home directory with these contents:

```
virtualbox --startvm Ubuntu_15.04 --fullscreen
```

You can then run `startx $HOME/startx_ubuntu1504 -- :1` to start the VM.

**From the login manager**

Create a file named `/usr/share/xsessions/vm_ubuntu1504.session` with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=virtualbox --startvm Ubuntu_15.04 --fullscreen
Name=VM Ubuntu 15.04
Comment=Run VirtualBox image in its own X session
```

You should then be able to select the X session from your login manager.  For example, I'm currently running Xubuntu 2016.10 with the lightdm login manager, and my current login theme has a session dropdown near the upper right corner.  This lets me select between any number of virtual machines or my non-virtual desktop.  Very cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can start the Virtual Machine headless, in [Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445284/how-to-start-a-virtualbox-machine-via-command-line-without-gui/449249) with:

```
VBoxManage startvm "VM name" --type headless
```

Once it has started, you connect your xsession into the already open Linux Virtual Box.

Disclaimer: I didn't try it because don't have a box to do it, but the theory says it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks fernando.reyes; yes, I think that should work.  I found something similar that works for directly starting with `startx` or a login manager, which I posted in my answer.